# Input radio выпадющее меню с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, menu

https://codepen.io/bogdan-babjchuk/pen/gObaeOR

Почему при выборе другого input-а не срабатывает

```
($idopt).fadeOut(300);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При выборе другого инпута, вы проверяете его же id. Тоесть, нажали trackers -> он стал активным, вы проверяете ЕГО же id, оно правильное -> и срабатывает первый if. Все время. + У вас переменная idopt инициализируется только при выполнении условия(внутри if). в else ее нет
Решение:

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
  $('.menu').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      var $idopt='.'+$(this).attr("id");
      $($idopt).fadeIn(300);
    } else {
      var $idopt='.'+$(this).attr("id");
      $($idopt).fadeOut(300);
    }
 });
});
```